# How do you make a video take up the rest of the div?

Tags: html, css

I need a the video to take up the space of the whole div. It shows that the controls do, but the thumbnail does not. Anyone have some advice, or can someone point me towards the right direction?

http://puu.sh/x6cUl/1b77983418.jpg

```
<div class="row videoRow hidden-sm-down">
  <div class="col-8">
            <video class="bigVideo" src="Myvid.m4a" allowfullscreen controls></video>
        </div>
        <div class="col-4">
            <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-6" style="margin-bottom: 2vw;">
                <video class="smallVideo" src="Myvid2.m4a" allowfullscreen controls></video>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-6" style="margin-top: 1vw;">
                <iframe class="smallVideo" src="Myvid3.m4a" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
            </div>
        </div>
</div>
```

and here is the css

```
.front-page .videoRow {
  padding: 20px;
}
.front-page .bigVideo, .front-page .smallVideo {
  border: black 2px solid;
}
.front-page .bigvideomobile {
    display: block;
    margin: auto
}
.front-page .bigVideo {
  width: 60vw;
  height: 30vw;
}
.front-page .smallVideo {
  width: 30vw;
  height: 14vw;
}
```

Comment: How can I help you without code?

Comment: Sorry about that. It's updated now.

Answer (score 1):

> HTML Example

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="left-container">
    <!-- Large Moive -->
    <video class="bigVideo" src="Myvid.m4a" allowfullscreen controls></video>
  </div>
  <div class="right-container">
    <!-- Small Moive 1 -->

    <!-- Small Moive 2 -->
  </div>
</div>
```

> CSS Example

```
.container{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  width: 800px;
  height: 300px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  align-items:center;
  justify-content: space-around;
}
.left-container{
  width: 500px;
  height: 280px;
  border: 2px solid black;
}
.right-container{
  width: 280px;
  height:280px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}

video{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

this code is just example code.

Key point is using display flex.

I hope this answer help you.

Comment: I updated the picture to show what I'm trying to ask. There is a space where the thumbnail doesn't go all the way, but the controls do.

http://puu.sh/x6cUl/1b77983418.jpg